# Jupyter notebook not running seccessfully

Tags: jupyter-notebook

picture for the error (https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXs7T.png)

the code for ddos attack detection
i got the code from this website  https://github.com/doriguzzi/lucid-ddos
i expect to run smothly but it didnt cuz its from github maybe i did something wrong !!

it has 3 files lucid dataset parse and lucid util functions and lucid cnn with 5 datasets it supposed to work together

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Especially the section 'Help others reproduce the problem' where it emphasizes not to use screenshots and to include all the traceback and what triggered it. When I look at the code at https://github.com/doriguzzi/lucid-ddos , I don't see any mention of running it in Jupyter. The README on the page you reference under [the section 'Command'](https://github.com/doriguzzi/lucid-ddos#command-options) is very clear on how to run the code using Python and not Jupyter. You cannot just copy code into a cell ...

Comment: <continued> and run it with an ipykernel kernel in Jupyter. Those are scripts meant to be run on the command line with `python <script> <arguments>` in the traditional way that Python code is run or in Jupyter with `%run <script> <arguments>`.